How to center two pads in Altium?
How to center two pads in Altium? I usually drag the component pads to perfectly center it but is there any better way to do this; any shortcut?


You can select both pads (click one, hold the Shift key, and click the other). Then press E G C on your keyboard (Edit -> AliGn -> Align Horizontal Centers), and click the pad you want to stay put. The other part will move horizontally to align with it.


